# SQL Server Transaction Log Backup File

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I am using SQL Server 2016.

I have setup SQL Agent for Full backup (Weekly) and Transaction Log backup (Daily).

Backup transaction log into a single file using:

```
BACKUP LOG [XXX] TO  DISK = N'E:\SQLDB\Backup\XXX_Trans_Log.bak' WITH RETAINDAYS = 28, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'XXX-Transaction Log Backup', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
```

What I expected is **only 28 days** transaction log backups will be kept.  But now I just found **All** transaction log backups are kept.  So the file grows to very large in size.

Is there syntax/option problems in the backup statement?

Or I should have to store in separate files?

What should I do now?

Comment: Almost ALWAYS it is better to create a separate file for each backup because it is easier to see your backups and easier to access them (since each one must be restored in sequence if needed).

Answer (score 0):

`retaindays` does not do what you are expecting it to do.

It prevents backup files from being overwritten, but it does not mean that old backups are automatically deleted.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want a solution that will do both backup and cleanup, try [Ola Hallengren's solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

PS: This question is better suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I does not expect automatically deletion, but old backups are never replaced.  Ola Hallengren's solution is too complicated to implement in our production environment.

Comment: By specifying `noinit` you are specifying append. But you don't want to specify `init` either! See [Aaron Bertrand's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/32908/154351) Just create separate files, and clean them up with an independent process. If you use Ola's stored procedure, it will handle this for you. I strongly recommend looking into it, yes it has a lot of arguments that you *can* use, but you can also use it in a very simple way.